# Какой IntentFilter у БД Контактов?

Tags: android, java, broadcast-receiver

Моё приложение должно отслеживать изменения в БД контактов. Если пользователь добавил, изменил или удалил контакт, то будут совершаться некоторые действия. Я решил,что разумно будет использовать для этого BroadcastReceiver, но мне необходимо знать IntentFilter при регистрации BroadcastReceiver в активити. Если знаете, какой IntentFilter у БД контактов или какой-нибудь другой способ всего этого,то прошу помочь... Тупая проверка каждые 5 минут "СЛИШКОМ ТУПАЯ", такой вариант не устраивает.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо через `BroadcastReceiver`, надо просто прицепить слушатель [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) к провайдеру контактов:

```
 context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver (People.CONTENT_URI, true, myContentObserver);
```

Comment: Посмотрел про ContentObserver. Есть вопрос. ContentObserver будет улавливать изменения в БД, даже если приложение выключено?

Comment: Нет конечно не будет слушать. Вообще правила хорошего тона рекомендуют перед смертью приложения снять регистрацию обсервера...

Comment: Ясно. Но у меня приложение постоянно должно отслеживать состояние БД контактов, могу ли я для этих целей зарегистрировать ContentObserver в Service? и будет ли он срабатывать,если телефон заблокирован или придётся дополнительно использовать PowerManager, чтобы пробуждать процессор?